# Help identify black cylindrical component with two blue rings

Tags: identification

Can someone help identify the component with the two blue lines?  I was testing the board for broken diodes and all of them checked out, but the VD prefix followed the labeling for the other diodes so that led me to believe it might be one as well.

It would a plus if you could help me figure out enough to get a replacement.

[image: Component]

[image: VD210]

Comment: I'm heavily inclined to say that the component is a diode because of 1)shape 2)marking on the PCB 3)and that VD may possibly stand for "voltage drop". If you have a multimeter, you can try to test it for diode properties.

Comment: I agree it's a diode too.  "VD" might indicate its a varactor diode as apposed to a rectifier diode.  If this board handles RF and needs to tune itself, then this is a real possibility.

Comment: The board came out of an air purifier.  It has features like sensing the air quality and adjusting the motor speed but nothing related to RF.  I'm testing out components because the purifier works on the LOW speed, but only occasionally on MEDIUM and just buzzes on HIGH.  It's out of warranty but the manufacturer stated it was probably a faulty diode.

All the other diodes checked out, but this gives a 0L reading on my multimeter regardless of polarity...of course it may very well be faulty but I'll have to figure out what it is to determine that and replace it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: If it is a HV diode it [consists internally](http://www.fujielectric.co.jp/company/jihou_archives/pdf/72-03/FEJ-72-03-187-1999.pdf) (that's in Japanese, but see figure on page 2) of more than one diode [junction] in series! So your DMM can't test that properly because it doesn't expect such a high forward voltage drop. It could well be that https://www.google.com/search?q=high+voltage+diode+cl04-12&tbm=isch

Comment: The indicator that it might be that are (1) elongated shape compared to a normal diode, and (2) two or more marking bands compared to just one for a regular diode.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdwbjNCK-xw for testing HV diodes.

Comment: Unfortunately I've gotten rid of it so I can't try the test in the YouTube video, but great find...hopefully it helps someone else.

A lot of the HV diodes I see pictures of appear reasonably larger than the one in this case, but other than that it does appear quite similar.